# PHP File Upload (files not written to temp directory with mode 777)

Tags: php, apache

I am uploading files to a PHP server. The upload directory is chmod'd to 777. The `$_FILES` array shows that it has written a temporary file to the upload directory, but when I `ls` the temporary directory, no file is present. Why?

Comment: The code you're using would be really helpful. Otherwise we're pretty blind :-)

Comment: try check permissions of your desire folder, with filezilla or through cpanel if its not set to read, write, execute that may be the problem. also use chmod 765 for web folders.

Answer (score 4):

Uploaded files are automatically deleted from the temp directory when the script exits. You **MUST** move/copy the files elsewhere yourself in the upload-handling script to prevent this. If you don't, PHP will clean up for you and nuke the file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this;

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$filename");
```